# Spring Authentication against an external API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I need to authenticate User against an external API where i need to pass the **username** and **password**. The API is a **REST web service** which will return be a **json object**. Now I need to extract the "**auth_token**"(an element in json) and set it in user context for further requests **since other requests need this auth_token to be set into the header** . There is no authentication logic need to be written at our end. All the login logic is taken care at API's end.
This is how the returned JSON Object look like:

```
{
  "success" : true,
  "auth_token" : "a2xvv-mqe_sV_Lhsggkd3Q",
  "email" : "****.***@***.com",
  "role" : "admin",
  "time_zone" : "Mumbai",
  "user_key" : "b3222tf92d",
  "sign_in_count" : 208,
  "organisation" : {
    "name" : null,
    "organisation_key" : null,
    "license" : {
      "license_key" : "tebde23823t5a76828e2et8683fd3b33e2eat5fb"
    }
  }
}
```

How to achieve this functionality in spring security.
It would be a great help if you provide me the steps with example if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say anything about how you get user credentials in your app. I will assume yo have a login form.

If this is your scenario, then you can configure Spring Security to manage this login form. Spring will get user credentials in form of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

Then you can create a custom `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider` and override this method:

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication);
```

In this method you can extract user credentials and consume the **REST web service** you mention.

Once you have the **REST web service** response, you can complete the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` with `AuthorityUtils`. I can't see roles, groups or similar in the json shown, I guess you can get this info from anywhere.

This way, overwriting `authenticate` method you will get with a valid `SpringSecurityContext` and fill your needs.

hope it helps!

### Edit

To answer comment I put a sample of auth method:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = null;
    Authentication result = null;
    User user = null;

    token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

    if (token != null) {
      if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(token.getName())) {

        if (YOUR_AUTH_METHOD(token.getName(), (String) token.getCredentials())) {

                //DO what you want to retrieve authorization

                String[] auxAuth = new String[size];

                //Put your roles, groups, ... into auxAuth
      //Role names must be ROLE_XXXXX

                result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    token.getName(), token.getCredentials(),
                    AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(auxAuth));
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

With this method you retrieve spring token, and then obtain login and password. Finally it manages roles for user authotization and then build a valid token for Spring Security Context.

Comment: i have implemented this method and also consumed the service. I also got  auth token. but as you said to complete "UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken", How to do that as there is no constructor to set the token ? Where to set Auth_Token that i have got.?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom [AuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html). See [this blog post](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own AuthenticationProvider and "inject it" in beans file.

Below is an extract of the sample class:

```
public class LdapAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {

        UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,
                authentication.getCredentials(), user.getAuthorities());
        result.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());
        return result;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
}

}
```

Then you need to inject it to AuthenticationManager like this:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

The response above assumes you understand the basic of security in Spring (User Details, Authentication token, Authentication Manager). If not please read [Spring Security docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) first.

Comment: where do the field "username" came from in method userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username) ??

Comment: @MayurGupta It came from authentication class. String username=(String)authentication.getPrincipal();